# Haskell Directory creates invalid symlink on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, windows-10, symlink

This year System.Directory was updated to include `createFileLink` and `createDirectoryLink` actions, and for me on Windows 10 both work fine for relative paths.

When I use either on an absolute path (of about 50 character length, so I suppose in unicode it exceeds 260) it prepends `\\?\` (i.e. `"\\\\?\\"`) to the paths, which can be seen from `DIR` as follows

```
<SYMLINKD>     source [\\?\T:\Code\hLink\binaries\dest]
<SYMLINK>      source.txt [\\?\T:\Code\hLink\binaries\dest\source.txt]
```

The directory link works fine, but the file link doesn't do anything, it doesn't even say that the target file is missing.

When I create a file link using `MKLINK` without `\\?\` in the absolute path it works fine as well, and when I create either link using `MKLINK`with `\\?\` it has the same result.

Is this a Windows problem? Can I make Haskell use short path format instead? (Using Win10 so apparently I can enable long paths via registry)
Should the Windows api be passing the `\\?\` header to symlinks at all?

**References:**

- MaxPath and the meaning of `\\?\`, plus disabling path limitations on Win10
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#maxpath
- Changelog reporting the addition of `\\?\` to win32 calls https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.1.1/changelog